# Is it possible to pull custom fields from SolidWorks files on Forge?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative, solidworks

I have translated SolidWorks files on AutoDesk Forge, however, the Forge metatadata / objects / properties call of these files only provides the objectid and name. I know I've got several fields in the files, just wondering if I have to wire up some strange way to pull them out before sending them, figuring it may not be supported through the Forge API. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The Model Derivative service is usually doing a pretty good job with extracting the metadata of your designs. Note however that the metadata might be available on a different level in the logical hierarchy.

Here's the metadata I see in one of my sample SolidWorks files when I simply click on one of the parts:

[image]

And this is the metadata I see when I select its parent element:

[image]

Comment: I see the data in the viewer, however I was more concerned with pulling the information through the API, I may have worded my question poorly! I wasn't sure they were there before so this did help!

Comment: Yep, if you see the data in the viewer, you can certainly obtain it without the viewer as well: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/accessing-design-metadata-without-viewer

Comment: I was being dumb, and my wrapper library around this endpoint (https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-metadata-guid-properties-GET/) had the wrong URL, but this endpoint was 100% what I actually needed.

Comment: I came across something unexpected. Anything under Custom Properties here: https://imgur.com/a/gFdmr80 does not come back via the API endpoint above, the fields that appear here are in the Configuration Specific tab in SolidWorks. I'll keep poking at things, but a lot of this is data processing the huge JSON that I've got.

Comment: This could be related to "property inheritance". The prop. database in the viewer allows objects to inherit properties from other objects in the logical hierarchy, and I'm not sure if the JSON response from the MD endpoint can do the same.